# Cloudkit Sync Problems

Tags: core-data, unique, synchronization, cloudkit, ckrecord

Am trying to implement Cloudkit sync with local cache (CoreData). Do you guys know where i can find a good tutorial or sample code. Apple mentions the steps we should follow for sync but there is no sample code to support it. Also how can we maintain the uniqueness of records while syncing ? In the developer mode can i access the private database from iCloudkit dashboard?

Comment: You are right that there is no great tutorials out there for how to get CloudKit syncing to work, even though Apple has given us the recipe. I'm writing up my CloudKit syncing journey [here](http://initwithfunk.com/blog/categories/ailcks/) which may be of some help. There is also an open source project called [CKSIncrementalStore](https://github.com/nofelmahmood/CKSIncrementalStore) that can sync a CoreData db with CloudKit without too much work.

Comment: Hi eirc i did implement the CKSIncrementalStore but had fews doubts consider the following scenario say I have a 1 to many relationship between parent and child in cloud that means CKrefe from child to parent with delete rule. Device 1, device2 and cloud are in sync with 1 parent and 1 child record
(a). Now from device 1, I add a record child 2 and upload to cloud 
(b). In device 2, I delete both child and parent and upload to cloud according to apple process of uploading local changes first. 
In this case my newly inserted child is deleted and i do not get any conflict on the parent record.